# Where to install bootloader on ubuntu? (boot with UEFI mode)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my Lenovo Ideapad 320S. It has a 4GB RAM with a 256GB SSD, boot with UEFI mode.
I chose "Something else" in the disk partitioning page in the Ubuntu installer.
After partitioning, there a box that requires me to choose where to install the bootloader:

[image: bootloader box screencap]

From my knowledge, there are 4 possible solutions I can use to install bootloader:

1. Create a ext4 partition, flag as /boot, and select this partition to install bootloader
2. Create a ext4 partition, flag as /boot, and select /dev/sda to install bootloader
   (not specifying any partition to install bootloader)
3. Create a FAT32 EFI partition and mark it as /efi. Now I have 2 EFI partition on my laptop.
4. Choose Windows Boot Manager partition as the location to install bootloader

Please tell me which possible solution I should use while installing bootloader, thank you!

Comment: You can only have one ESP - efi system partition per drive. Ubuntu's Ubiquity will only install to the first drive's ESP. The choices in Something Else do not work. Most desktops do not need /boot and often better not to have one unless using full drive encryption and then you cannot dual boot. and new installs now use swap file, so no swap partition. With both UEFI & old BIOS installs you always choose a drive like sda or firm NVMe drive to install into, not to a partition like sda2. Never install boot loaders to NTFS partitions, as that can damage Windows boot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Windows is already installed, you should have an EFI partition available and this is the partition to use. Make sure it is actually "used as" an EFI partition mounted on /boot/efi (do not format it again).

If you are not using LVM, LUKS, etc; a dedicated /boot/ partition is not necessary.